# How can I create my web page's background with my own animated Gif?

Tags: website-design

I have an animated Gif.  I would like to make it as my web page background.  Please let me have HTML/CSS code for this.

Comment: This is not a graphic design question, it should be in the main stack exchange. also.. gif background?? ew.

Comment: Ill give you an advice: Dont use a gif anywhere on the web unless you have no other chance. Also try and google before you ask questions usually youll find a solution :)

Comment: Belongs on stackExchange... why is that not an option under "belongs on another site in the network"?

Comment: @mayersdesign also this question would be down hammered on SE quite quickly since it does not belong there as its a request for somebody to wirte code with no effort on their part.

Comment: @joojaa - Yes that's true, certainly as its written

Answer (score 2):

Animated gifs as full page backgrounds are not a particularly good idea because of the enormous file size such a gif would have to be. GIFs are not suited to very large sized animations. It would be better to have a video file as the background.

This is not strictly a graphic design question, but if you are interested in a technique to add video as a background to a web page, there is some code (html 5, CSS, and JavaScript) and an example shown here: https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/knqyK - I have no affiliation with this website.